# Is there a known design pattern or antipattern for the implicit classification of scnarios by the execution path

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Is there a design pattern or anti-pattern for an approach when you keep a union of all needed properties in your base class without creation of dedicated derived subclasses. Different cases are
handled by different execution paths, which is achieved by sets of conditions on this properties.
Let me illustrate it with an example. Suppose you have public class `Figure`:

```
public class Figure
{
    public double? Radius { get; set; }
    public double? A { get; set; }
    public double? B { get; set; } 

    public double GetArea()
    {
      if (Radius != null)
         return Math.PI * Radius.Value * Radius.Value;
   
      if (A != null && B != null)
        return A.Value * B.Value;
      else if (A != null)
        return A.Value * A.Value;
      else if (B != null)
        return B.Value * B.Value;
      else 
        return double.NaN;
    }
}
```

Here in this class instead of a class hierarchy you have a union of properties and a `GetArea` method that checks them. Depending on the execution path a `Figure` instance can be a square, rectangle or circle.

This example is taken to the extreme. In a more complex context of our business application proponents of this approach argue that it allows to flexibly declare different sub-kinds of class (for example, an order or tax) without the addition of complex type hierarchy and with no need to keep all of them explicitly. So' I'm curious if this is a known design pattern.

Comment: This doesn't look like good design to me at all. Why would you want to do this? This just clutters up the method. It would be much better to have subclasses which represent a specific shape and override the `GetArea()` method. Other programmers would have to look at the properties of a `Figure` object just to determine what kind of figure it is, and that's if they can remember the logic which goes with certain properties having values. Using subclasses makes each object specifically known to the programmer.

Comment: This code smells, but I actually think this is a good question. This design is definitely the opposite of object-oriented, but it has its uses for certain corner cases. For example, if you are parsing a flat file with fixed column headers but different types of records (rows) with different optional column values. If it is a [anti]pattern with a name I would like to know what it is too.

Comment: I have not said anywhere that I would want to do this. But I actually encountered it in the large code base at my work, at several places. I became more interested with this recently. During my work on a new feature there was a heated discussion about a new type hierarchy I introduced. The case was not as extreme as my example - two subtypes of a entity which share all data except one property.  So it was suggested to fit it all into one class, and distinguish two cases (or more cases later) by checking it in the calling code.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this approach because in my opinion it makes logic widely spread all over the using code. It also makes rules and conventions for entity less explicit (you can introduce some helpers with good names to mitigate this). Still there are some pros which I mentioned. With this approach you will get not a hard coded explicit class but a kind of "weak typing", a variety of combinations with implicitly defined behavior via conditions set on property values. Perhaps this design is beneficial for some cases. So I would like to know if it was described by someone.

Comment: I couldn‘t find a proper name(just composition over inheritance?), but I see it relatively often used for serialization. Long time ago we used it for protobuf(maybe it supports now inheritance), also with json. When you have Order and Type types, you add the respective properties to the data object like {‚Order‘:...,‘Tax‘:...} having the same structure in C# with proper types. Then you simply call Deserialize and for example take first not null property. This is pretty helpful.

Comment: But for you case it looks for me like nothing else but imprinting -  100 years ago before inheritance was invented, we wrote so, so we‘ll keep doing that now. I mean this „ without the addition of complex type hierarchy and with no need to keep all of them explicitly“ looks like a strange argument to me, because instead of complex type hierarchy we get much more complex logic in some method. 
„ keep all of them explicitly“ I would say the opposite with explicit types it would become much more readable.

Comment: This seems to be a candidate for the [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) antipattern.

Comment: After thinking a bit more about this code it reminded me the object/data anti-symmetry described in "Clean Code" by Bob Martin:
https://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/oop/naited/Clean%20Code.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A237%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-48%2C671%2C1%5D


Here's the quote: "Procedural code (code using data structures) makes it easy to add new functions without changing the existing data structures. OO code, on the other hand, makes it easy to add new classes without changing existing functions.The complement is also true"

Comment: So maybe this can be called a pure procedural approach (not sure if it can be called a pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your needs. Usually it is better to create dedicated derived sub-classes, because it separates, and easy to understand.

But I agree, in some cases it might be easier to maintain all the flows in one class.

As for your question- there is no such design pattern, or anti-pattern. (at least currently)